# How to fill the DOP (date of birth) on discord register page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, discord

I'm new to Selenium and I'm trying to create a python code that automates the creation process of creating a discord account
but when it comes to filling in date of birth info I can't get the right class_name of each field and my code stops in selecting month step and do not select the month (I have no permission to insert photos yet )

mostly the issue comes from this part

```
month_dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(.//*[@class='css-19vtg9u-control'])[2]")))
month_dropdown.click()

month_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f".//div[contains(@id,'react-select') and .//div[text()='{get_month_number_from_name(month)}']]")))
month_option.click()
```

because the whole code works correctly as what I want until it comes to inputting the month and going to the next step, and this is the code that must be responsible for the month's input
also, I think there is a problem with the XPath of the element from the discord page because dropdown it's a dynamic element and I couldn't get the class_name of it so I used the XPath.

```
from typing import KeysView
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

def get_month_number_from_name(month_name):
    month_mapping = {
        'January': '1',
        'February': '2',
        'March': '3',
        'April': '4',
        'May': '5',
        'June': '6',
        'July': '7',
        'August': '8',
        'September': '9',
        'October': '10',
        'November': '11',
        'December': '12'
    }
    return month_mapping[month_name]

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

driver.get('https://discord.com/register')  

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='email']"))).send_keys("mo.key1998.1@example.com")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='global_name']"))).send_keys("Your Display Name")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']"))).send_keys("TheUltimateMoreda")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']"))).send_keys("msafan2006")

day_dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(.//*[@class='css-19vtg9u-control'])[1]")))
day_dropdown.click()

day_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(@id,'react-select-2-option-') and text()='1']")))
day_option.click()

month = "January"
year = "1998"

month_dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(.//*[@class='css-19vtg9u-control'])[2]")))
month_dropdown.click()

month_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f".//div[contains(@id,'react-select') and .//div[text()='{get_month_number_from_name(month)}']]")))
month_option.click()

year_dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(.//*[@class='css-19vtg9u-control'])[3]")))
year_dropdown.click()

year_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f".//*[contains(@id,'react-select-4-option-') and text()='{year}']")))
year_option.click()


time.sleep(200)
driver.quit()
```

please anyone help on this issue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You seem to be under the impression that repeating yourself multiple times helps to clarify your question (perhaps in response to Stack Overflow prompting you for additional information).  It does not, and instead it is often perceived as lazy or even rude and demanding, which is counterproductive to solving your problem.  Please take some time to edit and clarify your question.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I'have edited my quesrion , is it fine now or there is any better edits @David

Comment: @mohamedreda: What [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) you have done and what specific operation in the code shown is first producing an unexpected result?  (If you're not familiar with using a debugger, now is a great time to start.)  "Please help me" isn't really a specific answerable question.  Help us to help you by providing specific information about the problem.

Comment: thanks for your useful tips i tried to change the code again  , Ii have tried to use a debugger is nothing changed
I think the error comes from the step of filling in the month step In the code that i shared above , thanks again for your help . @David
but why i getting to many dislikes in just20 mins 

Comment: @mohamedreda: *"I think the error comes from the step of filling in the month step"* - Why specifically do you think that?  What specific debugging observation(s) have you made?  Which specific line of code isn't producing the result you expect?  What specific result (or lack thereof) is it producing?  Is there an error?  An unexpected side-effect?  Something else?  What specific result were you expecting?  What specific data is that line of code using?  Why specifically were you expecting that result?  Debugging is an exercise in critical thinking and testing, not just "I used a debugger".

Comment: Again, thanks for your help and your valuable tips @David , and excuse me because I'm still a beginner and I'm still trying to learn and get some experience.
I have edited the question again please take a look and give me your feedback